# If a set of vector functions in$\Bbb R^n$ is linearly independent, are their gradients linearly independent as well?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of vector functions of $t: [x(t), y(t), z(t) ...]$ that are linearly independent, is the list $[x'(t), y'(t), z'(t) ...]$ also linearly independent? If not, under what circumstances would it be?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. Consider the simplest possible case of a single function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$. Then $[f]$ is a linearly independent list, but $[f']$ is not since $f' = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but try to understand the reason why. Start with a linear combination being equal to the zero function: $$a_1x_1'(t)+\cdots + a_nx_n'(t) = 0.$$You would like to prove that $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ are all zero. Integrating, you have $$a_1x_1(t)+\cdots + a_nx_n(t) = c$$for some constant $c$. **If $c=0$, then linear independence of the original functions would give $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$**. If $c \neq 0$ you can't conclude anything, and you have no control over the value of this constant $c$. See Mark Saving's answer for the literally simplest example possible.